# Conditional Aggregations of Columns Using Pandas GroupBy.agg()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a following table

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| b | 0 | 2 | 6 |
| b | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| c | 0 | 1 | 6 |
| d | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| a | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| a | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I want to groupby columns `['c1', 'c2']` and sum column `'c3'` conditional of 'c4'==4 or 'c4'==6 or 'c4'==0.

Given a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['c1'] = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a']
df['c2'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
df['c3'] = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0
df['c4'] = [4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 0, 0]
```

I know I can do the following to calculate the sum of column `c3` with out any condition on `c4`.

```
calc_sum = lambda x: sum(x)
df.groupby(['c1','c2']).agg({'c3':('Total',calc_sum)}).reset_index()
```

My question is inside the `.agg` call, can I pass two columnns ('c3', 'c4') and replace the function `calc_sum` by a conditional sum like `calc_conditional_sum` as defined below?

```
def calc_condtional_sum(c3:list, c4:list, val:float):
    c3 = np.array(c3); c4=np.array(c4)
    ## Return the sum of those rows of column c3 where c4 is equal to `val`
    return c3[np.where(c4==val, 1, 0).astype(bool)].sum()
```

A friend of mine suggested doing `df[df.c4==4].groupby(['c1','c2']).sum()`. And this is a perfect solution if I were only looking for only one value in columnn `c4`. However, I want to calculate the sum of `c3` for all unique values of `c4`.

I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

No, `agg` uses single columns. You cannot access the other columns*.

You can however us `apply`:

```
l = [0, 4, 6]

out = (df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'])
         .apply(lambda g: g['c3'].where(g['c4'].isin(l)).sum())
       )
```

Or, filter the rows to use before grouping:

```
out = df[df['c4'].isin(l)].groupby(['c1', 'c2'])['c3'].sum()
```

Or, create first a Series, then `agg`:

```
out = (
  df['c3'].where(df['c4'].isin(l))
 .groupby([df['c1'], df['c2']]).sum()
)
```

Output:

```
c1  c2
a   0     4
    1     0
b   0     5
c   0     1
d   1     2
dtype: int64
```

* actually, you can if you use a side-effect, but this is a bit ugly and wouldn't work with chained commands:

```
m = df['c4'].isin(l)

out = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'])['c3'].agg(lambda g: g.where(m).sum())
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.

I actually want the sum of each condition (`c4==4`, `c4==6`, and `c4==0`) separately. So that in your output table there would be three columns for each condtions.

Comment: Please provide the explicit expected output in your question for clarity. You likely need to add `c4` to the `groupby`